# How To Remove 'Index' from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do you remove 'Index' the following URL
    siteName/controller/Index/8
into
    siteName/controller/8
and still it will access the Index method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using default routes, it's because "Index" is the default value for the action route parameter:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

This means that if the {action} is ommitted from an inbound URL, MVC will use the default, meaning it will go to the Index action method.

Same thing with the {controller}: if you omit /controller from the URL, it will go to the HomeController (and its Index action method) because they are the default values for the default route mapping.